# Problem with understanding an equation

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, matrices, fourier-analysis

I have read the article [Short-wavelength Spectral Properties of the Gravity Field from a Range of Regional Data Sets](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00190-005-0011-y) and I don't know how to interpret Equation (10) on
page 630, because this equation modified matrix $\Phi_2$ to vector and I don't know how. 
Authors comment to this equation is "This is done by dividing the $\Phi_2(v_p,v_q)$ matrix into classes according to $\sqrt{v_p^2+v_q^2}$ and computing class mean values."

The equation (10) has the form
$$
  \Phi_2(v)=\Phi_2(\sqrt{v_p^2+v_q^2}),
$$
where $\Phi_2(v_p,v_q)$ is the matrix of a Fourier transformation computed by
$$
F(v_p,v_q)=\sum_{k=0}^{K_x-1}\sum_{l=0}^{K_y-1}f(x_k,y_l).e^{-i2\pi(pk/K_x+ql/K_y)},
$$
with $p=0,1,...,K_x-1$ and $q=0,1,...,K_y-1$. The corresponding 2D-power spectral densities  is
$$
\Phi_2(v_p,v_q)=|F(v_p,v_q)|^2
$$

Comment: this paper is behind a paywall

Comment: I modified my answer so that it is best to understand even without opening article.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\Phi_2(\nu)=\int_0^{2\pi}\Phi_2(\nu\cos\phi,\nu\sin\phi)\nu d\phi$$

in words, you start from a function defined on the two-dimensional plane, and you average over the angular coordinate to arrive at a function that depends only on the radial coordinate.